# Using から with short/informal writing

Tags: particle-から, informal

My question is about using から when writing short form/informal speech in a sentence ending in a verb. For example, if the formal version is:

A「猫はちょっと太っていますね。」
B「ええ、よく食べますから。」

Would the informal/short version of Speaker B's part be written:

うん、よく食べるから。
Or:
うん、よく食べるだから。

Or some other way?

(This is for an assignment where we take a written long form/formal conversation and rewrite it as informal/short speech.)

Comment: I would say its 食べるから

Answer (score 1):

だから = だ (casual copula) + から (because)

だから is basically the casual form of ですから. You can't use です with a verb in ます form, so ですから wouldn't work in the formal version and だから wouldn't work in the casual version since だ is the copula and you already have a verb - 食べる.